# A list has been obtained from an outside soft (from COMSOL - to Mathematica). Let us make a continuous function out of it

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction

Using COMSOL I have solved an equation. The solution in the form of nested list with the term `{x,y,z}` is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/21mven0okp5oaei/trial.xlsx?dl=0).
This

```
lst = Flatten[
   Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "trial.xlsx"] /. {x_, y_, z_} /; 
      Abs[z] < 10^-6 -> {x, y, 0}, 1];
```

imports the list, provided it is in the same directory as the working notebook. That's how it looks like:

```
ListPlot3D[lst, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

My aim now is on the basis of this list to build a smooth enough function which I could use for a further post-processing. In particular, I need to make a rather special integration.

I am trying the following idea: let us define a function, `g(x,y)` such that for each point `{x,y}` it takes the value `z` of the point whose coordinates in the XY plane are the nearest to the point `{x,y}` in this plane.

I tried the following. Here is the list of XY coordinates of the points of the original list, `lst`;

```
lstXY = Transpose[Transpose[lst][[1 ;; 2]]]
```

with this list I make the function in question:

```
g[X_, Y_] :=lst[[Position[lst, Join[Flatten[Nearest[lstXY, {X, Y}]], {a_}]][[1,1]]]] // Last
```

One can check that it, indeed, returns a value:

```
g[-60, 50]

(*  0.123899 *)
```

One can look up at its plot:

```
    Plot3D[g[X, Y], {X, -65, 139}, {Y, 0, 129}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

[image]

The image is tolerable, though not as good as the initial one. One can evidently make it better by taking more PlotPoints.

However, even the simplest integral

```
NIntegrate[g[x, y]^2, {x, -65, 139}, {y, 0, 129}]
```

yields the error messages:

1: Nearest::nearuf: The user-supplied distance function dist does not give a real numeric distance when applied to the point pair {x,y} and {-70.,0.5}.

2: Heads Nearest and List at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the \
same.

3: "Part 1 of {} does not exist."

And others. I guess that the problem number 1 generates all further messages.

Two questions:

1. My function appears to be very slow. Any ideas to make it faster?
2. I cannot understand, what does Mma not like during the integration process?

Note: There is an alternative way to achieve my goal. It is to make an interpolation function. This I tried, but when checking the plot of this interpolation function is appears considerably worse than the initial plot. So, I would like to first check this idea.

Comment: Did you try `g[X_?NumericQ, Y_?NumericQ] :=...` ?

Comment: @ Ulrich Neumann Yes, the result of the integration is the same.

Comment: Ok , unfortunately I cannot access your data link. With similar function `g[X_?NumericQ, Y_?NumericQ] :=...` the integral `NIntegrate[g[x, y]^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Method -> "MonteCarlo"]` evaluates without error message!

Comment: @ Ulrich Neumann Not in my case. I guess, something is wrong with my function definition.

Comment: Seems like [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) would do what you want, or do you have a reason not to use it?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch If I try (with your definition of g)  `g[a,b]` Mathematica gives the same error message as you got as first message. That's why I think you need to use `_?NumericQ`

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann  I tried with ` _?NumericQ` as well as with the MonteCarlo method both separately and together.  In my case this did not work, and I received that strange message.

Comment: @Lukas Lang Yes, it does. However, Interpolation gives rise to some other problems. They should also be somehow solved. I still do not know, which ones are  easier to solve. I discuss it shortly in the very end of my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your approach with [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) is basically equivalent to some sort of zeroth order interpolation. It would be much better to just use [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation) with `InterpolationOrder->1` instead. So:

```
lst = First @ Import["/Users/carlw/Downloads/trial.xlsx"];
if = Interpolation[lst, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot3D[if[x, y], {x, -65, 139}, {y, 0, 129}, PlotPoints->100, ColorFunction->"Rainbow"]
```

[image]

Looks pretty close to your [`ListPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot3D) output.

Now, when integrating interpolating functions you typically need to specify a method to help out the integration routine, otherwise it will complain. For example:

```
NIntegrate[if[x, y]^2, {x, -65, 139}, {y, 0, 129}]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 11407.712189266926`and 0.12073887656623529` for the integral and error estimates.
>
> 11407.7

Instead of specifying an integration method, I like to use [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue). So:

```
NDSolveValue[
    {
    Derivative[1,1][int][x, y] == if[x, y]^2,
    int[-65, y] == 0,
    int[x, 0] == 0
    },
    int[139, 129],
    {x, -65, 139},
    {y, 0, 129}
]
```

> 11511.5

Finally, with your approach, it is much simpler to use:

```
Clear[g]
nf = Nearest[lst[[All, ;;2]] -> lst[[All, 3]]];
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := First @ nf[{x, y}]
```

Then:

```
NIntegrate[g[x, y]^2, {x, -65, 139}, {y, 0, 129}]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 11408.50499919936`and 8.71116765190886` for the integral and error estimates.
>
> 11408.5

The reason `_?NumericQ` didn't work for you is probably because you didn't [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear) `g` before defining the `_?NumericQ` version, and so your old definition of `g` was still active.

Comment: Thank you. Please comment on the following question: do you see a possibility to make an interpolations function with the `InterpolationOrder` equal to 2 or 3? This would be necessary, if I need to calculate derivatives of my solution, rather then only integrals. To make `InterpolationOrder->3` Mma requires to make interpolation on a structured grid.

Comment: (Continuation) In principle, I thought about the function `g[x,y]` just for the purpose of making such a structured grid as follows: `tab = Table[g[x, y], {i, -70, 140, 10}, {j, 0, 130, 10}]; f = ListInterpolation[tab, {{-70, 140}, {0, 130}}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3];` or alike. However, it takes more time. For example, plotting of `f` with `PlotPoint->100` yields a nice-looking result, but requires 50 s in comparison with 0.4 s of plotting `if`. The same with the integration. If in the expression for `tab` I make the iterator 1, it takes "infinitely" long.